# External jQuery Library in typescript file

Tags: jquery, typescript, smartadmin

i am working on an Asp.net MVC project with Smartadmin theme and Typescript with JQuery typings for Dom manipulation, there is a jquery library called SmartMessageBox for prompt messages ,is there an easy way to use this library inside my typescript file because i get 
Error Build:Property 'SmartMessageBox' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'

Comment: You can write a declaration file describing the library. If you post a link the project documentation maybe I could help, but I can't find the library on a simple search

Comment: you need to have type definitions for that plugin or you can cast `jQuery` to `any` before using the `SmartMessageBox` property, eg. `(jQuery as any).SmartMessageBox(args)`

Comment: @Roomy that is a possibility, but not a very safe one, if the library is simple, it might pay off to write the declarations . Maybe even contribute them to definitely typed ;)

Comment: unfortunately it's library written by the theme creator i think,i couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the message box is only used in one file**, the easiest solution is to add something like this at the top of the file:

```
declare const jQuery: JQueryStatic & {
    // *** Choose one of the following ***
    // Most basic:
    SmartMessageBox: any;
    // Better (assuming SmartMessageBox is a function):
    SmartMessageBox(/*param type info*/): /*return type or void*/;
};
```

This says `jQuery` is a global object whose type is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of the interface `JQueryStatic` and the interface describing `SmartMessageBox`.

**If the message box or other "smart admin" types are used in multiple files**, you should look into writing a .d.ts file. The [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) and the [default jQuery .d.ts file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts) should be helpful in figuring out what to do. Save the file under `<project root>/typings/smart-admin/index.d.ts` and add the following in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
    }
}
```

This tells the compiler to look for type definitions under `./typings` as well as `./node_modules/@types` (the default location for `@types` packages installed from npm).

Answer (score 0):

You must create a d.ts file for SmartMessageBox.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html